# Where to save JSON response from api?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm new in react. Right now i'm working with axios . I'm getting back JSON file with data. I need to store it somewhere . Where I should store it? in localStorage or in state? Later I need to map it and display that data. What is the best and efficient way. Right now I'm storing It localStorage and in state. Than from state mapping it

```
getTemplates() {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token")
    axios
      .get("http://dev.candidates.hrmessenger.com/stage/get-template", {
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      })
      .then(res => {
        localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(res.data))
        this.setState({
         data:JSON.parse(localStorage('data'))
       })

      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }



this.state.data.map((item, index)=>{
return (
<div key={index}>{item}</div>
)
})
```

Comment: why are you storing it in local storage then setting it to state, why not set directly to state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should store the data in the state and call setState if you want to change the state data again, its the best way to get the data i.e the response and set it in the State so you don't have to clear the local Storage. and local Storage is not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use Redux and Redux-Persist .
[Redux-Persist Reference](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)